# I would like the URLs to your blogs

Tags: discussion, serverfault, blog, users

I'm looking to compile a list of blogs that users here write as I'd like to follow them.  If you are an active member and want to share your sites to be followed, please post them below.

Comment: I've been slammed between work, family, and personal projects of late and have posted in months... Maybe I'll make some time tomorrow morning now that I'm reminded.

Comment: Wouldn't posting such URLs be advertising, which is a no-no?

Comment: @John That's kind of why I specified active members, and posted in Meta as suggested by Zypher.  If it gets out of hand with spammers down the road, we can close it.  But for now I sort of see it as SF-meta-community-building.

Answer (score 5):

http://blog.serverfault.com (of course :) )

and less frequently updated:

http://brokenhaze.com

Answer (score 4):

http://core.eti.br it's in portuguese but I am thinking about blogging in english from the next month onwards.

I try to make a point of not going more than one month without a technical post ;)

Comment: I was pleased to find that Google Translate actually did a halfway decent job of translating even your technical articles. Sure, it was somewhat awkward as are all machine translations, but very understandable, at least the posts I read.

Answer (score 4):

Just getting started on this blogging lark after a long hiatus, but http://itsalwaysmyproblem.com/

Answer (score 4):

Mine is linked in my profile page.

Answer (score 3):

A very bad blog... but still a blog [Jacob's blog](http://JacobJernigan.com)

Answer (score 3):

I'm new around here, but with the intention to stay here for long time :-) Here's my [blog](http://hmontoliu.blogspot.com) (just to distract me from time to time but focused mostly to gnu/linux)